# caesar cipher object doesn't support assignment python

Tags: python, algorithm

Write a method that takes in an integer `offset` and a string.
 Produce a new string, where each letter is shifted by `offset`. You
 may assume that the string contains only lowercase letters and
 spaces.

```
def caesar_cipher(offset, string):
    words = string.split(" ")

    word_i = 0 
    while word_i < len(words): 
        word = words[word_i]

        letter_i = 0 
        while letter_i < len(word):
            char_i = ord(word[letter_i]) - ord("a")

            new_char_i = (char_i + offset) % 26 
            word[letter_i] = chr(ord("a") + new_char_i) #----error is at this line ----

            letter_i += 1
        word_i += 1 
    return words.join(" ")
print caesar_cipher(3, "abc")
```

print should return def.

would like to know how to fix this str assignment error please and thank you!

Comment: Can you show *any* evidence that you have tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: Strings are immutable. Create a new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable.

```
a = "hello"
a[1] = 'q'
```

..results in this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

A better approach is to build up new a list of 1-character strings out of the substituted letters. In idiomatic Pythonic, that would be a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but a for-loop would also work fine.

Lastly, join them into a new string like this:

```
''.join(cipher_chars)
```